# Can I connect an indoor timer to lights split to 3 circuit breakers?

Tags: electrical, lighting, timer

Currently the lights in the store turn on from 3 separate  circuit breakers, I have to flip each circuit breaker to turn on each light zone. I would like to connect an indoor timer that will turn on all the lights from all 3 breakers at once.

How do I connect it?

Comment: If this is in a commercial retail space you should just call an electrician. He'll know exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Either 3 timers, one on each circuit, or one timer, controlling 3 relays, one relay on each circuit. The timer and relay control can be on a 4th circuit, or on one of the three circuits if there is capacity available.

Whatever device does the switching needs to be adequate to handle switching the load - that is, the relay contacts must be rated to carry as much (or more) current and voltage as is being switched on. One advantage of using relays is that the timer contact only needs to be sized for controlling the relay coils, generally a much smaller load.

Answer (score 0):

Hello A timer and one lighting relay is all that is needed and the experience to hook it up God Bless Big Jim